# Pandas selection keeping the same shape as original DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, selection, dataframe

I'm trying to select from a DataFrame with multi boolean criteria keeping the original size of DataFrame.

Suppose that i have the follwing DataFrame :

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from random import randint
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [randint(1, 9) for x in xrange(10)],
                   'B': [randint(1, 9)*10 for x in xrange(10)],
                   'C': [randint(1, 9)*100 for x in xrange(10)]})
>>> df
   A   B    C
0  3  40  100
1  6  30  200
2  7  70  800
3  3  50  200
4  7  50  400
5  4  10  400
6  3  70  500
7  8  30  200
8  3  40  800
9  6  60  200
```

I want to select the values where 10 < B < 70 and C = 200 without changing the DataFrame size.
I've tried the query function:

```
df.query('10 < B < 70 and C == 200')
```

and I'm getting this:

```
   A   B    C
1  6  30  200
3  3  50  200
7  8  30  200
9  6  60  200
```

but I want this:

```
   A   B     C
0  3  40   NaN
1  6  30   200
2  7  NaN  NaN
3  3  50   200
4  7  50   NaN
5  4  NaN  NaN
6  3  NaN  NaN
7  8  30   200
8  3  40   NaN
9  6  60   200
```

I'm aware of df.where function but apparently it's not possible to apply for columns, it works just for all DataFrame.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
df.B[(df.B < 10) | (df.B > 70)] = np.nan
df.C[df.C != 200] = np.nan
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a nice workaround solution, but I'm trying to use the built-in functions from Pandas. Thanks again.

Comment: @npires, I also try to use built-in functions but sometimes it is impossible )

Comment: I think there is a way using just Pandas with 'where' method:  `df.B.where((df['B'] > 70) & (df['B'] < 70)),  df.C.where(df['C'] == 200`  but I'm wondering if there is a simpler solution.